# Latex3: Correct implementation of macro that generates other macros

Tags: macros, latex3, bm

I am implementing a latex package, and internally I have defined a routine **\genMacroVect** that generates a series of commands which inherit some properties from a class called **vect** which at the same time inherits the properties from **nom**.

Everything works properly, but I have noticed that for some of the cases the latex compiler throws an error due to the lack of brackets **{ }**. I susspect there are some **\expand** (latex2e) missing somewhere, but i haven't figure out how to define this using the latex3 synthaxis. I would really appreaciate if someone would take some mins to take a look.

Here I provide a simplified version of the program:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\RequirePackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{bm}


% ----------- General command
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { nom } {
    A .tl_set:N = \l__amtyp_nom_A_tl,
    B .tl_set:N = \l__amtyp_nom_B_tl,
    A .initial:n = {},
    B .initial:n = {},
}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \nom }{ m O{} } {
    \group_begin:         
    \amtyp_nom:nn { #1 } { #2 }
    \group_end:
}

\cs_new:Nn \amtyp_nom:nn {
    \keys_set:nn { nom } { #2 } 
    #1 \c_math_subscript_token  {\mathtt{\l__amtyp_nom_A_tl \l__amtyp_nom_B_tl } }
}

% ------ Case vector
\keys_define:nn { vect } {
    of .meta:nn = { nom } { B={#1} },
    wrt .meta:nn = { nom } { A={#1} },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vect}{ m O{} } {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { vect } { #2 }
    { \nom{#1} }
    \group_end:
}

% ------ Macro generating macros
\NewDocumentCommand{\genMacroVect}{ mm }{   
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{ O{} }{
        \group_begin:
        \keys_set:nn { vect } { ##1 }
        { \vect{#2} }
        \group_end:
}}

% ---- Macros generated using previous definition
\genMacroVect{\vel}{ {v} }
\genMacroVect{\aoa}{ {\alpha} }
\NewDocumentCommand{\vela}{ }{ \vel \c_math_subscript_token a }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}    

\begin{align}
\nom{a}[A=A, B=B] \\
\vect{r}[of=A, wrt=B] \\
\vel[of=A, wrt=B] \\
\vela \\
\bm{{\vel}} \\   % <--------- It compiles
\bm{\vel}        % <--------- Faulty case
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in your definitions that is causing the problem, you can simplify the test example to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}

\NewDocumentCommand\zzvel{O{}}{\alpha}

\begin{document}

$\alpha+\zzvel+\bm{\alpha}+\bm{\zzvel}$

\end{document}
```

**Warning the above document will loop forever and the latex process will need to be killed**

This is simply that `\bm` can not interpret a command form that was written some decades after the package.

As noted in the `bm` package documentation surrounding the argument in braces causes it to fall back on the safer (but slower and with potentially worse spacing) `\boldsymbol` mechanism.

It may be tricky to make `\bm` unravel all `\NewDocumentCommand` forms sufficiently to be able to natively determine a bold version but probably simple cases like this could be handled, but not today.

Comment: I see, I tought there was something wrong with the code. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @WDsgn https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/748 (so I don't forget)